# Cookies not working when page accessed via file://

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My code works in firefox and when i visit w3schools using chrome to test my code in their editor it works fine too but when i launch my code in chrome from notepad++ it doesn't work.It seems that body onload is not working because i don't get the alert.My chrome is up to date.Help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays){
var d=new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires="expires="+d.toUTCString();
document.cookie=cname +"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}
function f(){
var user=prompt("What is your name?","");
if(user!="" && user!=null){
setCookie("username",user,30);}
}
function getC(cname){
var name=cname+"=";
var ca=document.cookie.split(";");
    for(var i=0;i<ca.length;i++){
        var c=ca[i];
        while(c.charAt(0)==" ")c=c.substring(1);
        if(c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
function checkcooki(){
var user=getC("username");
    if(user!=""){
    alert("Welcome back "+user);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="checkcooki()">

<input type="button" onclick="f()" value="klick">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain "in chrome from Notepad++" ... Are you testing on a `file://` protocol? Cookies are domain driven, so no cookies for you, if you don't use a (local) webserver => `http://`

Comment: Put the alert outside of the `if` to test if it is going into the function. If you get an alert then it's the `if(user!="")` that's returning false

Comment: @Elizion his function name matches

Comment: How do you know that it's not being executed? When you open the file from your local disk, you probably won't have a cookie.

Comment: Presumably `user` is not set, so your alert isn't getting hit.

Comment: I can confirm it works fine for me in an up to date Chrome.  file:/// protocol.

Comment: @tangent In that case, never mind me ... :)

Comment: i am using file:/// protocol and it works in firefox but not in chrome..probably the user is somehow not set..but how can it be set in firefox and not being set in chrome...strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fact: Using the `file://` protocol does NOT guarantee the proper workings with cookies. Since cookies need 3 things:

- A name-value pair containing the actual data
- An expiry date after which it is no longer valid
- The domain and path of the server it should be sent to

*The domain tells the browser to which domain the cookie should be sent. If you don't specify it, it becomes the domain of the page that sets the cookie.*

On a `file://` protocol you don't have a domain.

Now some browsers might have found work-arounds for this, like FireFox and IE. You can test your code on these browsers but they will not use cookies in the same way as on a webserver.

Proper x-browser testing in your case requires the `http://` protocol.
I suggest you start a jsfiddle or setup a webserver(IIS, apache).

Proper read on cookies: [quircksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

If you are still persistent to get it working on chrome through the `file://` protocol you might have a small chance if you get the path correctly.

- path: properly escaped path => `encodeURIComponent(document.domain)` or `"c:\/my%20folder\/index.html"` (along these lines but again, very untrustworthy information here)
- domain: `"/"` (no idea what else you can try here)

Comment: ok i started wamp and it's working now..http protocol..thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your user variable must be a blank string.

Put an alert at the very top of your checkcooki() function to verify that body onload works.

Comment: i did and the alert is triggered so body onload works.So why it is not working inside the if condition?

Comment: @admir because user variable is empty check http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/f7rwasLw/1/

Comment: @admir Because your cookie is not set.

Comment: ok guys i can confirm that cookie is not being set in chrome and the user variable is empty..now i am confused why it is being set in firefox using the same code but not in chrome...is there some kind of workaround?

Comment: How many days are you setting your cookie to expire in? Maybe the int is too big and it's wrapping around.

Comment: @Mex it's 30 days as you can see in the setCookie function 30*24*60*60*1000

Comment: Add alert(d.toUTCString()) to eliminate the int wrap around. If it says the valid date then the issue is something else.

Comment: @Mex if i add alert(d.toUTCString()); at the and of the setCookie function i get an alert saying "Sat, 14 Mar 2015 19:00:00 GMT"